# heat map control

Tags: c#, winforms

i am looking for a winforms solution for a heatmap control.  Essentially if i have a bunch of sales data and i have different dimensions (region for example), i want to visualize the profit and loss per region and also factor in the size of the region.

Similar to this:
http://www.smartmoney.com/etf/maps/

does anyone recommend a third party control or other suggestion to get this done quick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dundas Charts has a Heat Map option.

http://www.dundas.com/Gallery/Flash/Chart/Other/index.aspx